# SGDClassifier on Big Data (sparse)

Tags: python, classification, data-science, sklearn-pandas

Hello everyone i am relatively new to the space of data science. I am trying actually to train a SGDClassifier with over 4000000 samlpes of data without any possitive results.

X vector has 6 features and looks like : [ 2 , 4 , 56431555 , 1 , 0 , 33]

Y vector has 1 feature which is the category. It can be 1 or 0... eg [1]

These are some examples of my data records :

X :

```
[[       2        4 56431555        1        0       33]
 [       2        1 71716268        1        0      623]
 [       0        1      302        0        1       33]
 ...
 [       0        4     3707        0        1       33]
 [       0        1   733126        1        0       33]
 [       0        4 30960953        1        0       33]]
```

Y:

```
[0 0 1 ... 1 1 0]
```

When i use the .predict() on test data the only result i get is that every test vector belongs to the class 0. So i get an array full of zeros.

This are the parameters for which i initialize the classifier

```
from sklearn import linear_model
model = linear_model.SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3)
model.fit(data_train, target_train)
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem? ( i have already tried to use standard scaling on my data)

Note : Avg: Loss on training is huge and when i scale my data is 0.97 which i dont know if this can show anything about my dataset or model

Comment: First of all, when you use SGD is highly recommended that you normalize your data. I would check the accuracy or the confusion matrix, these are more interpretable than loss value and could give a clue about your current problem, because if you only get zeros could potentially be a problem of imbalance dataset

Comment: Yes indeed is an imbalanced dataset! I have fixed the problem using the proper normalization. Thank you